# The update is an atomic operation? (update stock)

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

Supose that I have a table that has a stock field.

- MyTable(ID, Stock, ...)

If I do:

```
Update Mytable set Stock = stock -5 where ID = 123;
```

Is the record 123 blocked before the update so I can be sure that the record has correct stock amount or is not a good way to update the stock?

Thank so much.

Comment: Nothing wrong with doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a sliding scale between concurrency and isolation. The more you get of one the less you get of the other. So, you can do something like this:

```
DECLARE @Stock int;
BEGIN TRAN

SELECT @Stock=Stock 
FROM dbo.MyTable
WHERE ID = 123 
WITH (UPDLOCK); --lock the row for update

--inspect @Stock to make sure it's what you're expecting

UPDATE dbo.MyTable
SET Stock = Stock - 5
WHERE ID = 123;

COMMIT TRAN
```

The downside to this is that anyone else trying to read the row while you have the transaction active. But it also ensures that nobody will update the row to a value other than what you think it is.

Comment: really the hint UPDLOCK block the row in the select? Because I tried another hints and there are cases in which the row is not lock, although is the expected. The only way that I find that works is do a first update inside a transaction to block. thank you so much.

Comment: I should have been more clear; other queries specifying UPDLOCK will be blocked. Think of it this way, in most cases, you don't want to block a select from reading the value from the table as that would seriously hamper concurrency. Instead, you just want a way to know that when you're about to update the value, that it hasn't changed out from under you. So, if you do something like the above (wrap it in a procedure perhaps?), you will have an opportunity to inspect the value and potentially abort your update if it's not what you're expecting.